# Ember tutorial- adding new routes to router.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been doing this tutorial to try and teach myself ember-

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/

I've successfully gone through it and am now trying to flesh it out a bit and add in my own functionality, but I'm new to ember and having a bit of trouble figuring it out. The original tutorial is a CRUD app for a collection of users. I now want to expand the app to deal with a list of subjects that these users might study. Im working through the steps, but am having some trouble figuring out how to modify the `router.js` file so that it contains my new `subject` route. The router looks like this-

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how it should look when a second route has been added? I'm confused by `this` being included when I'm referring to more than one route. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to deal with `subjects` per `user`, you will need to change your `router.js`, like so:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
      this.route('subjects');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
});
```

Given this router file, you going to have these routes:

- `/users`
- `/users/:user_id`
- `/users/:user_id/edit`
- `/users/:user_id/subjects`
- `/users/create`

If you just want to create another route, then:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');    
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
  this.route('subjects');
});
```

Routes:

- `/users`
- `/users/:user_id`
- `/users/:user_id/edit`
- `/users/create`
- `/subjects`

To help you out and avoid confusion, I would suggest using [Ember Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi). It helps you out quite a bit.